# Identity core - cannot log in after change key type

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I try to setup identity in my application. I created Razor Pages project and I added New scaffolded item -> Identity. Then appeared new folder - Areas which contains all identity related stuff.
One thing I want to change is change Primary Key for User. I want int instead of Guid. I followed many tutorials and posts on this site, but something is wrong. I am able to register new user, but I cannot login. If I try login, I am redirected to homepage but I still see Login link instead of Logout and of course all views marked with `[Authorize]` are inacessible for me.
I will show what I changed, and I believe that one of you will notice one piece of code I missing.

IdentityContext

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int> { }
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int> { }

public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

IdentityHostingStartup

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();

            });
        }
    }
```

Startup

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

And I have changed all occurrences of `IdentityUser` into `ApplicationUser`

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing both an `IdentityContext` and `ApplicationDbContext`, both of which inherit from `IdentityDbContext` and use your customized Identity entities. It's hard to say with the code you've provided, but my best guess is that you're creating the user with one, and attempt to login with the other. You only need one of these contexts, not both. Remove one and then ensure that everything is using the same context.

Comment: You are right. One context was unnecessary so I removed it, but this issue still occur